# Ant - skip task, when directory does not exist

Tags: ant, javac

I have set of projects, that use build file from "parent" project. All works fine until each project contains *test* directory.
Now I have a new project, that have no tests yet, so I would like to do not run *tests* task if the *test* directory does not exist. (Original script fails with `srcdir "C:\.jenkins\jobs\Cenne Papiry\workspace\test" does not exist!`.)
I'd tried to set *test.src* property only if *test* directory exist:

```
<available file="test" property="test.src" value="test"/>
```

and condition the *tests* task on existence of *test.src* property:

```
<target name="tests" depends="compile-tests" if="test.src">
```

*test.scr* property is not set, but *ant* tries to execute *tests* task still:

```
C:\Users\vackova\workspace\commons-agata\build.xml:246: srcdir attribute must be set!
```

(`<javac target="1.8" debug="true" srcdir="${test.src}" destdir="${class.dir}" encoding="UTF-8" >`)

How can I achieve my aim?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163998/do-i-have-any-way-to-check-the-existence-of-a-directory-in-ant-not-a-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334939/how-to-check-if-directory-exists-before-deleting-it-using-ant

Comment: I seem to recall that if and unless on target want a boolean value (true|false) in the property.

Comment: @HankLapidez that applies to ANT >= 1.8. Prior to that it's only a check whether the property is defined.
Either way the "available" task only sets the property if file exists. That said the code from above works for me.

Comment: @CiaPan your links ask, what I know (*<available file="test" property="test.src" value="test"/>* - this works fine), my question is completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct and should work in most ant versions. Here's a snippet for testing that should run standalone, tested in ant 1.7.1 and 1.9.4:

```
<project name="bar" default="tests" basedir=".">

    <available file="foo" property="test.src" value="anything"/>

    <target name="tests" if="test.src">
        <echo message="folder or file foo exists"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: This works. Thanks, but full answer is: 
1. Property must not be defined:
I had *<property name="test.src" value=""/>* and in *init* task: *<available file="test" property="test.src" value="test"/>* - **It doesn't work**.
2. A task which fails needs to be conditioned also, so I need not only 
*<target name="tests" depends="compile-tests" if="test.src">*, but also
*<target name="compile-tests" description="Compile tests sources" depends="compile, retrieve-for-tests" if="test.src">*

Comment: Right. the "if" condition evaluates to false if the property is not defined OR if it is defined and evaluates to false. Simply don't define it and you're fine. Important point to note: ANT properties are not changeable. That means if you set the property first, you won't be able to set it to something else anymore. Quote from docs: "Properties are immutable: whoever sets a property first freezes it for the rest of the build; they are most definitely not variables."