# ANT: Using conditional tags, <IF>

Tags: ant, tags, if-statement

I would like to do something like this

```
<target name="clean" description="clean">
    <if>
        <available file="${build}" type="dir" />
        <then>
            <delete dir="${build}" />
        </then>
    </if>
</target>
```

As per [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163998/do-i-have-any-way-to-check-the-existence-of-a-directory-in-ant-not-a-file) found on stackoverflow.com, i downloaded ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar and put it into my path

[image: Classpath]

Additionally, under Ant Build configuration, in classpath, i have
[image]

When running my ANT script, i still get

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Repositories\blah\build.xml:60: Problem: failed to create task or type if
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

**What am i missing? Please advise**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alternately, once can include the following line in your ANT script

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />
```

As long as `ant-contribs` is in your path, nothing else is needed

This solution is a bit cleaner, as one **gains access to ALL the tags,** not just the ones manually specified

Comment: even cleaner is to load the task definitions from antlib via namespace, f.e. <project xmlns:ac="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib">, see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html

Answer (score 5):

Same issue resolved in that way.
I put at the start of the buid XML file the following lines:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="your/path/to/ant-contrib-${version}.jar" />
  </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Answer (score 3):

The standard ant way would be something like =

```
 <target name="check">
  <condition property="delbuild">
    <available file="${build}" type="dir"/>
  </condition>
 </target>

 <target name="delbuild" depends="check" if="delbuild">
 <delete dir="${build}"/>
    <!-- .. -->
 </target>
```

A snippet with the [Ant Plugin Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/), a recent alternative to antcontrib. Installation in Eclipse as usual via
 Preferences | Ant | Runtime | Global Entries | [ant-flaka-1.02.-1.02.jar](http://flaka.googlecode.com/files/ant-flaka-1.02.02.jar) =

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
  <!-- some standalone if construct -->
  <fl:when test=" '${build}'.isdir ">
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
  </fl:when>

    <!-- some if/then/else construct -->
    <fl:choose>
     <!-- if -->
     <when test=" '${buildtype}' eq 'prod' ">
        <!-- then -->
        <echo>..starting ProductionBuild</echo>
     </when>
     <when test=" '${buildtype}' eq 'test' ">
        <!-- then -->
    <echo>..starting TestBuild</echo>
   </when>
    <!-- else -->
     <otherwise>
      <fl:unless test="has.property.dummybuild">
       <fail message="No valid buildtype !, found => '${buildtype}'"/>
      </fl:unless>
        <echo>.. is DummyBuild</echo>
     </otherwise>
    </fl:choose>
</project>
```

output with ant -f build.xml -Dbuildtype=prod or
ant -f build.xml -Dbuildtype=prod -Ddummybuild=whatever

```
[echo] ..starting ProductionBuild
```

output with typo => ant - build.xml -Dbuildtype=testt

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/rosebud/workspace/AntTest/build.xml:21: No valid buildtype !, found => 'testt'
```

output with ant -f build.xml -Ddummybuild=whatever

```
[echo] .. is DummyBuild
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue. I resolved in the following way.
Sometimes this might be compatibility problem.

- Right click on build.xml.
- Go to "Run As" --> 2 Ant... Select Classpath tab check Ant Home version (Sometimes eclipse selects default ant version).
- If the version listed is different, then change    Ant Home Classpath
  to C:\XXXX\ant\X.X.X.
- Finally click on the User    Entries --> Add External JARS..--> add
  ant-contrib.x.x.jar form    C:\XXXX\ant\X.X.X\ant-contrib\ directory.

Comment: Thank you so much !
I had to download the jar file on it's own here : http://goo.gl/xZe5c8

Answer (score 1):

On the tasks tab for your Ant Runtime do you see the 'if' task?

Comment: Hmm ... I do not. What is the name of the task that you have it? I assume, i need to pick the ant-contrib jar file and pick a class containing the task? What class is it?

Comment: Yes that is correct.
I do not use 'if' but in this case it looks like  net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask is the corresponding class.

Answer (score 1):

`export ANT_HOME=/path/to/ant/apache-ant-1.8.2`

I couldn't get it to work until I had ANT_HOME set properly. Java kept picking another ant installed on the box.

Comment: For me it was similar. Just mentioning this, to raise awareness, that this error message is also send, if you have the "if" task included correctly, but some filepaths, for example to the required jar are not set correctly